# Spring object saving issue using MySQL and Java CommandLineRunner

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I have this exercise I'm doing and upon trying to create an object and store another one in it, I receive an error for duplicate information on the object, although there is no other one as it. It's like MySQL is creating an invisible object somewhere.

I'm using Spring with Java and just two classes with @ManyToOne and @OneToMany relationship. My dto's contain the standard @Data from Lombok plug-in. Please, ignore the entered information, as it's just for testing. Thanks!

Here is the Artist.class which stores the artist songs:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "artists")
public class Artist {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String labelName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String aboutInfo;

    @Column
    private GenreType genreType;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "artist_song",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "artist_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "song_id"))
    private Set<Song> songs;

}
```

Here is the Song.class which has an Artist:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "songs")
public class Song {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String albumName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int yearPublished;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Artist artist;

}
```

I'm using the following save() method in my Service for Song.class via dto's:

```
@Override
    public SongDto save(SongDto songDto) {
        Song song = modelMapper.map(songDto, Song.class);
        String artistName = songDto.getArtistDto().getName();
        Artist artist = modelMapper.map(artistRepository.findByName(artistName), Artist.class);
        song.setArtist(artist);
        songRepository.save(song);
        return modelMapper.map(song, SongDto.class);
    }
```

And now here is the ApplicationRunner.class that I am using to test this, and which brings the CommandLineRunner exception that tells me the Artist object is duplicating:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    private ArtistService artistService;
    private SongService songService;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationRunner(ArtistService artistService,
                             SongService songService){
        this.artistService = artistService;
        this.songService = songService;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        ArtistDto michaelJ = new ArtistDto();
        michaelJ.setAboutInfo("asdasd");
        michaelJ.setGenreType(GenreType.POP);
        michaelJ.setLabelName("Michael Jackson");
        artistService.save(michaelJ);


        SongDto thrillerSong = new SongDto();
        thrillerSong.setAlbumName("MJ Album");
        thrillerSong.setName("Thriller");
        thrillerSong.setYearPublished(1986);
        thrillerSong.setArtistDto(michaelJ);
        songService.save(thrillerSong);

    }
}
```

This is the exception(I'm using my own exception class DuplicateResource.class which extends RuntimeException):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:807) [spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:788) [spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) [spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) [spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.project.Spring_Project_Artists.SpringProjectArtistsApplication.main(SpringProjectArtistsApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
Caused by: com.project.Spring_Project_Artists.exception.DuplicateResourceException: Cannot save this object due to duplicate information.
    at com.project.Spring_Project_Artists.service.ArtistServiceImpl.save(ArtistServiceImpl.java:65) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.project.Spring_Project_Artists.ApplicationRunner.run(ApplicationRunner.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804) [spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Thank you for any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using? You should be using an in-memory database for this, since if it's something like MySQL then the data is persisted and when you run your app the second time, it can't insert since the record is already there.

You should use something like h2, which is in-memory and won't store the data so when you re-run your app, it should be able to insert again.

[This tutorial uses an in-memory database (h2); try using the same dependency](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, I am indeed using MySQL. I have managed to fix this just about 5 minutes ago. It was an issue with my entity mapping. If anyonye is reading this at a later time, please check this link - https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many

Thanks for your reply!